# java one element list

Tags: java

What is the most efficient (performant) way to create a list with just one element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use:

- [`Collections#singletonList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList%28T%29), which returns a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), or
- [`Collections#singleton()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton%28T%29), which returns a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Collections.singletonList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) for a list of 1 element.

Comment: @Cœur the point of the forum is to provide a good answer to the question. The same answer was already given and this did not provide any other useful information. There is no reason the poster can't just delete the answer. Two others did delete the answer. And my comment is for the future as well so people learn.

Comment: @Cœur I realize that  you are a monkey, so I'll try to keep this simple.  This answer landed almost at the same time as the other.  It is not uncommon for two people to be answering a question at the same time and the answers to post within minutes of each other.

Comment: As in my Chinese zodiac sign? Anyway, I'm removing my comment. And note that I can't see deleted posts like you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [`Collections.singletonList(T o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) mentioned in other answers, there's [`List.of(E e1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E)).  This is the single-element overload of the [unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) static factory methods, which create unmodifiable lists of arbitrary sizes.

While the current implementation has a small bit of additional overhead compared to `singletonList`, it is likely to be similarly performant to `singletonList` in practice.